# How do you declare reference pointers?

Tags: c++

```
main()
{
 int *a; 
 myfunc(a);
}

myfunc(int & *b)
{
 //'b' is a pointer with the same address as 'a'
 //so if you change what 'b' points to, it also changes what 'a' points to
}
```

The above doesn't work. Now this is no big deal as you can just use double pointers to do the same thing, it just seems simpler to be able to have reference pointers.

```
main()
{
 int *a;
 myfunc(&a)
}

myfunc(int **b)
{
 //de-referencing b once will give you the 'a' pointer
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `int *&b`, a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Ya I tried on another compiler and that worked. So * goes before &, maybe that order is crucial.

Comment: @user3015682 The answer below does mention that `int *&` is a possible solution.

Comment: @user3015682: If you think the existing answer(s) are not complete, then you can either (1) submit an edit proposal to one of the existing answers to add information or you can (2) create your own answer.

Comment: The one answer uses the type alias, which is optional, but really all that is needed is putting * before &. Since stackoverflow refuses to let me delete, and someone keeps editing the solved in the title (ugh) I'll mark as answer anyways in hopes that I can get on to other things. Good grief.

Comment: One should be able to remove the question if the premise of the question is in error. You can do what the question said you can't, you just need to take care of the sign order is all. This is no longer a question and answer deal, it's more like a public service message: be careful of the sign order.

Comment: Wasn't trying to rob anyone's reputation, rather I found the question to be based on an erroneous assumption. BTW my comment "OK, I'll edit those out." was in response to a comment that has been sense deleted, in case someone is wondering what that was in response to.

Comment: *"rather I found the question to be based on an erroneous assumption"* But still, one day someone might have the same problem, and then this thread will help them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be "reference pointers"; you simply misspelled it. It's best to look at it through the lens of type aliases, as they remove all of the `*` syntax. If you have:

```
using Type = int;
Type val = 5;

void func(Type &ref);

func(val);
```

It's clear what that means. So it means the same thing when you change `Type`:

```
using Type = int*;
Type val = /*get a valid pointer*/;

void func(Type &ref);

func(val);
```

`ref` here is a reference to the pointer object passed to the function.

To spell this out more directly, a reference to an `int*` is `int *&`. Read it right-to-left: a reference to a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> it just seems simpler to be able to have reference pointers.

Sloppy<sup>*</sup> writing can lead to muddied understanding. You are not talking about "reference pointers" but "references **to** pointers". The "to" is important for putting "reference" on equal footing with "pointer". "Reference" should be a noun here, not an adjective. The "to" is also significant because "pointer" also gets a "to"; in your example, the pointer is *to* an `int`. Put this together: you are looking for a reference *to* a pointer *to* an `int`. This full description is key. Once we get the word "`int`" into the description, the rest flows naturally.

*<sup>*</sup>In this context, any negative connotation to "sloppy" should be ignored. Sloppy phrasing is common and accepted in conversational English. However, programming holds one to a higher standard of precision.*

You showed that you know how to declare that `a` is a pointer to an `int`. The declaration starts with `int`, proceeds to the symbol indicating "pointer to", then ends with `a`:

```
int       *               a;
^         ^               ^
an int    a pointer to    a is
```

The declaration is a reversed reading of *"`a` is a pointer to an `int`"*. The same strategy applies to most declarations, in particular to the thing you want: *"`b` is a reference to a pointer to an int"*. Read in reverse:

```
int       *               &                 b;
^         ^               ^                 ^
an int    a pointer to    a reference to    B is
```

You cannot have a pointer to a reference to an `int`, but you certainly can have a reference to a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ya since compilers accepts 'int* i" and 'int * i' and 'int *i' It seems like * doesn't really go with 'int' or with 'i', just has to be somewhere in between. I've noticed lately that Visual C++ now puts the * next to the var type. Though like English "The sky is blue" and "The blue sky" both convey that the sky is blue, regardless of noun/adjective order. Reference means the parameter address is the same as the argument's, and pointer means the value is an address, and the value is an int in this case.

Comment: Last comment should have ended like: the value found at the address pointed at is an int in this case. (I missed the comment editing countdown)